# How to get polymer version 1 starter-kit with polymer cli?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

If I run `polymer init` it's only possible to select templates of polymer 2.0.

Is it possible to select templates of polymer 1.0 too?
If it's possible, how can I do this?

Comment: You can do it. Check https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/templates.

Comment: Thank you for your bei comment, but I get just Polymer 2 Templates to choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Polymer 1.x templates with polymer-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042699/how-to-install-polymer-1-x-templates-with-polymer-cli)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `polymer-cli` is too new. First downgrade it to the last version that supports Polymer 1.0 templates, which is `1.1.0`.

```
npm install -g polymer-cli@1.1.0
```

Then try running the CLI again and you should see polymer 1.0 templates.

```
polymer init
```