# How to install Polymer 1.x templates with polymer-cli

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

When I run `polymer init`, it only shows V2 templates, but I want V1. How do I install Polymer 1.x application/element templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pending issue ([`polymer-cli` Issue #804](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/804)) to restore the 1.x templates. In the meantime, you can manually install them with:

```
npm i -g justinfagnani/generator-polymer-init-polymer-1-element \
         justinfagnani/generator-polymer-init-polymer-1-application
```

This will allow the 1.x templates to be listed when running `polymer init`.