# polymer 1 "polymer init starter-kit" return this error: Template polymer-init-starter-kit:app not found

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm following the instructions on the official polymer page:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up

but when I execute this command:

polymer init starter-kit

I receive this error:

error: [init]   Template polymer-init-starter-kit:app not found
error: [cli.main]   cli runtime exception: Error: Template polymer-init-starter-kit:app not found
error: [cli.main]   Error: Template polymer-init-starter-kit:app not found
    at Object. (C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\lib\init\init.js:223:19)
    at Generator.next ()
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\lib\init\init.js:17:58)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

my version polymer-cli: 1.7.2
my version node is: 8.11.2
my version npm is:5.6.0
my version bower is: 1.8.4

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Polymer 1.x templates with polymer-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042699/how-to-install-polymer-1-x-templates-with-polymer-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this commands:

git clone https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-starter-kit.git

cd polymer-starter-kit

git checkout v2.2.0

bower install

regards